# In HLSL pixel shader, why am I getting [-256.0, 256.0] values in SV_POSITION input?

Tags: input, directx-11, hlsl, pixel-shader

My question is basically in my DirectX11 pixel shader, why am I getting a range of values from -256.0 to 256.0 in the SV_POSITION input instead of the supposed values from 0.0 to ViewportWidth and 0.0 to ViewportHeight?

I am setting explicitly the viewport right before the draw call and when debugging with PIX, the state of the Device Context is showing me the viewport values correctly. I need to do a fast lookup to a buffer that has the same dimensions as the render target so I might as well wanted to save interpolating some textcoords to the pixel shader.

Am I missing something that is setting up the ranges incorrectly?

Comment: How are you determining that SV_POSITION in the pixel shader can be negative? I'm not aware of any circumstances under which that can occur.

Comment: You need to provide your input layout description, your vertex shader inputs and outputs, and your pixel shader inputs to get any help with this...